# Flash AS3 Call a WSDL in a for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, soap, wsdl

I'm using the Flex SOAP web service, connecting to our WSDL and everything is dandy.  However, I'm new to web services and the web guy is on holiday, so I'm a bit confused.  The first thing I'm doing is running a check connection:

```
private function configXMLHandler(event:LoaderEvent):void {
        fws.wsdl = checkWSDL;
        fws.loadWSDL();
        fws.addEventListener(LoadEvent.LOAD, wsdlLoaded);
    }

    private function wsdlLoaded(event:LoadEvent):void {
        checkAbstract = fws.getOperation("retrieveAssetIdbyLabel");
        checkAbstract.arguments = ["poll-asset-do-not-remove"];
        var token:AsyncToken = checkAbstract.send();
        token.addResponder(new Responder(checkAbstractResult, checkAbstractError));
    }

    private function checkAbstractError(event:FaultEvent):void {
        trace('Error in the WSDL');
    }

    private function checkAbstractResult(event:ResultEvent):void {

        if (event.result.returnCode == 0) {
            trace('Web service check ok');

            initContentLoader();

        } else {
            trace('Error in the WSDL');
            )

        }

    }
```

This works fine, I get the result I expect, and so I move on.  I then need to iterate through an XML list and call the same web service function for each asset in that XML, my thinking was to use a loop:

```
private function initContent(event:LoaderEvent):void {
        assetList = event.target.content.asset;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < assetList.length(); i++) {
            assetAbstract = fws.getOperation("retrieveAssetIdbyLabel");
            assetAbstract.arguments = [assetList[i + assetCount].assetLabel];  //get the current index in the xmllist + the assetCount, grab the corresponding assetLabel from the XML and pass that to the web service
            trace(assetAbstract.arguments);
            var assetToken:AsyncToken = assetAbstract.send();
            assetToken.addResponder(new Responder(getAssetResult, getAssetError));
        }
    }

    private function getAssetResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
        var treasuresAsset:TreasuresAsset = new TreasuresAsset(event.result.returnCode, assetList[assetCount].asset.assetLabel, assetList[assetCount].asset.assetImage, assetList[assetCount].asset.assetDescription);
        addChild(treasuresAsset);

        assetCount++;  //increase the asset count
    }

    private function getAssetError(event:FaultEvent):void {
        trace(event.fault);
        trace('An error occured when we tried to get an asset id in the loop');
    }
```

I now get an error:

> Error opening URL 'http://www.nhm.ac.uk/web-services/VisitorService/'
>   SOAPFault (Server): org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement RetrieveAssetIdbyLabel

My immediate thought was that I need to create a new instance of the web service for each asset in the xml, and repeat my first code over and over.  Can I use the web service only once, do you need to recreate the entire procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured this out, and it was a simple XML namespace issue.

I replaced:

```
assetAbstract.arguments = [assetList[i + assetCount].assetLabel];
```

With:

```
var sender:String = assetList[i + assetCount].assetLabel;
            assetAbstract.arguments = [sender];
```

And all is working.